# How can I copy styles from a template to another document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

I want to copy the styles of a template from the Word template folder or any other folder I prefer via a command in VSTO Word Add-in and pass the copied styles to a document.

Please how do I do this. I have been searching through and have seen that it is possible but haven't been able to get the slightest hint about the c# codes to use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to copy styles from a template to a document opened in Word. One is by using the Organizer (originally used in Word Basic, so it's a bit primitive) and the other is by attaching the template with the styles to the document then forcing an update of the styles.

The first allows selecting only specific styles, but it also means running the copy for each style, individually. Note that the styles are specified by *localized name* - there is no option for using the language-independent `wdBuiltinStyle` enumerations.

The second forces the document to adapt *all* the styles in the source template. It has the "side effect" of also making any Building Blocks, keyboard shortcuts and macros available to the document, through the link to the template. And any of these things that were made available through the original template will no longer be available. This last can be remedied by re-attaching the original template *without* updating the styles after doing so (see the second code sample).

**Organizer**

```
    private void btnCopyStyles_Organizer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tmplPath  = @"C:\Test\StylesTemplate.dotm";
        string[] aStyles = {"Heading 1", "Heading 2" };

        for (int i = 0; i == aStyles.Length- 1; i++)
        {
            wdApp.OrganizerCopy(tmplPath, wdApp.ActiveDocument.FullName, aStyles[i],
                Word.WdOrganizerObject.wdOrganizerObjectStyles);
        }
    }
```

**Attach the template**

```
    private void btnCopyStyles_AttachTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tmplPath  = @"C:\Test\StylesTemplate.dotm";
        Word.Document doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
        doc.set_AttachedTemplate(tmplPath);
        doc.UpdateStyles();
    }
```